# ¿Como generar un usuario en MySQL que solicite renovación de contraseña cada cierto tiempo?

Tags: mysql, sql

El siguiente comando me sirve para generar un usuario a nivel de consola en MySQL

```
CREATE USER 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH sha256_password BY pass;
```

Con el siguiente comando le asigno permisos

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost';
```

Y finalizo con

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

> Sin embargo la duda es: ¿Cómo lograr que el sistema genere la petición
>   de una nueva contraseña cada determinado tiempo para un usuario en
>   MySQL cada determinado tiempo?

Nota aclaratoria: El plugin de cifrado `sha256_password` que se lee en la sentencia `SQL`, esta disponible desde la versión **5.6 de MySQL**; aquí la fuente

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sha256-pluggable-authentication.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Al tiempo que estamos generando un usuario dentro de la consola de MySQL, podemos establecer el periodo dentro del cual el gestor va a solicitarle al usuario creado una nueva contraseña

```
CREATE USER 'admin'@'localhost'
IDENTIFIED WITH sha256_password
WITH 'password'
PASSWORD EXPIRE INTERVAL 2 DAY;
```

Donde, justo después de indicar la contraseña asignada al usuario en cuestión:

1. `PASSWORD EXPIRE INTERVAL`: Me va a permitir indicarle al gestor que la contraseña va a ser renovada
2. `2 DAY` es un periodo de ejemplo donde le estoy indicando que cada dos días la contraseña será solicitada de actualzar cuando el usuario en cuestión; en este caso admin desee iniciar sesión

> Puedes establecerle un mayor o menor rango de tiempo deacuerdo a
>   necesidades; cabe mencionar que esta característica se encuentra
>   disponible desde la versión 5.7 del gestor antes mencionado

Ahora por el contrario si deseo que la contraseña asociada a un usuario recién creado nunca expire; el comando debería quedar del modo siguiente

```
CREATE USER 'alfas'@'localhost'
IDENTIFIED WITH sha256_password
BY 'demon'
PASSWORD EXPIRE NEVER;
```

Comment: Excelente pregunta/respuesta Alfredo. Sólo señalar que se puede hacer también de manera global mediante [`default_password_lifetime`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_default_password_lifetime). Esta opción es útil en el caso de que se quiera establecer el mismo período de expiración para todos los usuarios, [tal y como indica el manual de referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/password-management.html#password-expiration-policy). Quizá es útil usar esta función combinándola con la *política de reutilización de contraseñas*.

Comment: gracias por la fuente @A.Cedano la revisaré para documentarme mas

Comment: Como nota muy al margen, pedir que un password de base de datos expire nunca deberia ser necesario. Quienes hacen las consultas a la base de datos son usuarios de programas, los cuales tienen passwords que no son usadas por personas. Y si estas password vencen, entonces hay que por lo menos tocar un archivo de configuracion del sistema y tambien volver a ejecutar ese sistema. Ningun programa deberia conectarse con un usuario nominal comun.